# What is a top-level function in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm reading 'Introducing Python' by Bill Ivanovic. In Chapter 4, the book says

> A set of mathematical functions which
>   compute statistics about an entire array or about the data along an
>   axis are accessible as array methods. Aggregations (often called
>   reductions) like sum, mean, and standard deviation std can either be
>   used by calling the array instance method or using the top level NumPy
>   function

And the author gives an example,

```
In [151]: arr = np.random.randn(5, 4) # normally-distributed data
In [152]: arr.mean()
Out[152]: 0.062814911084854597
In [153]: np.mean(arr)
Out[153]: 0.062814911084854597
In [154]: arr.sum()
Out[154]: 1.2562982216970919
```

What does it mean by a top-level function in Python?
Among the three functions in the example, which one is a top-level function?

Comment: `np.mean()` is. A top-level function refers to where the function is defined or accessible; at the top level of a module. `array.mean()` is a method on an instance of the `numpy.array` class.

Comment: Please do include *context*. Are you reading a tutorial or blog post or other documentation that you are trying to understand? There is no standardised term here, so context could help clarify.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok. I will fix it.